# mod_wsgi (with anaconda python on mac os x) uses wrong libpython library

Tags: python, macos, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I try to use mod_wsgi with a non-system python installation (anaconda). But mod_wsgi always uses the libpython provided by the system python. How can i change the configuration to use entirely anaconda python?

Setup:

```
Mac OS X 10.10.3
Python 2.7.9 :: Anaconda 2.2.0 (x86_64)
system provided Apache/2.4.10 (Unix)
mod_wsgi-4.4.11 src
```

I installed mod_wsgi with:

```
./configure --with-python=/opt/anaconda/bin/python2.7
make
sudo make install
```

--the with-python option points to the anaconda python binary. Normally this should be sufficient to use anaconda python.

apache configuration

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so
...
WSGIPythonHome /opt/anaconda
WSGIScriptAlias /~dlangenk/wsgi/test /Users/dlangenk/Sites/wsgi/test.wsgi
```

test wsgi application

```
import sys 

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'

    output = ''
    output += 'sys.version = %s\n' % repr(sys.version)
    output += 'sys.prefix = %s\n' % repr(sys.prefix)
    output += 'sys.path = %s\n' % repr(sys.path)

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

output of test script

```
# if everything would work sys.version should point to the 2.7.9 python version of anaconda
sys.version = '2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]'
sys.prefix = '/opt/anaconda'
sys.path = ['/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg', '/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg', '/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi_metrics-1.1.0-py2.7.egg', '/opt/anaconda/lib/python27.zip', '/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7', '/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/opt/anaconda/Extras/lib/python', '/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL', '/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.2.3-py2.7.egg', '/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa', '/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography-0.8-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg', '/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-15.2-py2.7.egg']
```

output of apache error log

```
[Mon May 18 10:41:11.656749 2015] [wsgi:warn] [pid 18114] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.9.
[Mon May 18 10:41:11.656929 2015] [wsgi:warn] [pid 18114] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.6.
```

What i already tried:

1)
When using mod_wsgi-express to setup a new apache installation bundled with mod_wsgi the anaconda python library is picked up correctly. But for different reasons I want to use the system apache.

2)
If i remove /usr/lib/libpython-2.7.dylib and replace it with /opt/anaconda/lib/libpython-2.7.dylib the output of sys.version is correctly shown as 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (x86_64)|... . But I cannot remove the system libpython library because the system python is used by Mac OSX.

3)
As suggested by the official [Documentation](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnMacOSX) although stated that it is fixed I modified the makefile to link against the libpython in /opt/anaconda/lib and further set the runpath to /opt/anaconda/lib. Nothing worked

Comment: When this has come up before the conclusion was that it seemed that Anaconda Python was breaking the ability of Python to be used in an embedded system. StackOverflow is not the place to try and resolve this as it is not a discussion forum. If you want further help with this one you will need to come over to the mod_wsgi mailing list.

Comment: BTW. You can simply install the result of building mod_wsgi-express into your main Python installation by running 'sudo mod_wsgi-express install-module'. Take the output of that script and use it as configuration to load module into main Apache configuration. If that doesn't work then something is really wonky with the Anaconda setup.